# Keep inventory_quantity attribute of variant in sync after a new order is issued in Shopify

Tags: shopify

In Shopify, there is an inventory_quantity attribute tied to a variant that describes how much of an item is left in stock at any given point.

I noticed the following behavior that looks inconsistent to me:

The variant attribute inventory_quantity is updated when the value is modified directly form the Shopify admin, triggering a Product/update webhook.

However, when someone orders that item, Shopify automatically decrements the item's quantity but does not trigger a Product/update Webhook.

Is that a bug or the expected behavior? (In which case, what it the best way to stay in synch with inventory_quantity values?)

Comment: Probably it doesn't fire the product/update webhook because the `inventory_quantity` belongs to the ProductVariant (a separate object). But ProductVariant's don't support webhooks. As a workaround you could register to the order/created webhook.

Comment: What puzzles me is that when a variant attribute (like price, variant title and even inventory_quantity) is modified using the Shopify admin and clicking save, a product/update webhook is triggered.

Problems arise when the inventory_quantity is modified due to the customers purchasing stuff (in which case a order/create webhook is issued but not a product/update one).

I was wondering if it was intentional or not as when you subscribe to product/update you kind of expect a webhook to be issued when an attribute changes, whether it's due to an action of the shop admin or the customer.

Comment: Yes, you're right. When admin changes to ProductVariants do trigger the product/update webhook, I don't see why it shouldn't for (backend) inventory updates.

Answer (score 1):

This one is expected behavior, whatever you want the same thing I have used in my case. And When order/create webhook is available then product/udpate shouldn't be sent due to dual requests which make confusing to our code side.

Use following to sync inventory-

1. order/create
2. product/update